# Does Python 2.6 have a built in URL parameters parser?

Tags: python

Given a URl, how can I get a dictionary of parameters back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

edit: It returns a tuple of the url parameters. If you absolutely need to have it be in a dictionnary looks like you will have to implement it yourself. (get the tuple then assign it to dict)

```
string = "addressing scheme network location path query fragment_identifier".split()
url = urlparse.urlsplit("url")

dictionary = dict(zip(string,url))
```

Not sure if that dictionary line is valid, but it's something like that.

Comment: I want the query parameters . >>> u.urlsplit("http://google.com/?a=3&k=2");
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com', path='/', query='a=3&k=2', fragment='')

Comment: TIMEX. parse_qs and parse_qsl come to your help.

Answer (score 2):

ofcourse, it is called [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html). However, instead of a dictionary, the urlsplit and urlparse methods output a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) object, which you are easily reference by member attributes. If dictionary is a must, you can construct one using those named tuple values too.
And if you want to parse the query params, use `parse_qs` and `parse_qsl` from the same module